# Sort Drives by Free Space in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to sort my drives using Powershell by free space. The purpose of this utility is to re-distribute one disk that is almost full across all the disks that are not as full.

Currently, my powershell script looks like this:

```
# Retrieves drives from My Computer
$Drives = gdr -PSProvider FileSystem

# Iterates over all drives found
foreach($Drive in $Drives) {
    $Drive | Sort-Object -Property Free
}
```

The output is this:

```
Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                                                           CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                                                           ---------------
C                 151.09        688.31 FileSystem    C:\                                                                              
D                   0.05         15.67 FileSystem    D:\                                                                                           
F                   0.09          2.96 FileSystem    F:\                                                                                           
G                   0.05         16.43 FileSystem    G:\                                                                                           
H                   0.03          9.73 FileSystem    H:\                                                                                           
I                   2.42         65.94 FileSystem    I:\
```

But I'm expecting something like the Free (GB) Column to be sorted ASC

Any clues?

Comment: You seem to be sorting *inside* the list over drives, why would that change the order they're in?

Comment: is `Free` the REAL name of the property? the display system often remaps prop names to "friendly names". you can find the REAL name by piping to `Get-Member`. ///// also, as `jonrsharpe` pointed out, you are not sorting the collection. try feeding the collection _directly_ into the `Sort-Object` cmdlet. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes FREE is the real name of the property

Comment: `Free            ScriptProperty System.Object Free {get=## Ensure that this is a FileSystem drive...`

Comment: @ILikeTacos - thanks for the feedback [*grin*] ... please read the added info in my comment for the real problem [as shown by `jonrsharpe`].

Comment: Excellent that worked! I figured out my mistake. Thanks @Lee_Daily

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I sorting the individual drive and not the collection as pointed out by @johnrsharpe and @Lee_Dailey

This ended up solving my problem:

```
# Iterates over all drives found
$SortedDrives = $Drives | Sort-Object -Property Used -Descending

foreach ($Drive in $SortedDrives) {
    Write-Output $Drive.Name
}
```